# C# handling UI - Output

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-forms-designer

Hello my fellow programmers,

this question is most likely pretty dumb, because I think I misunderstood something in my C# class at school.

The task is to create a simple UI-Form to check if a Website is available. The UI is already done and consists of 4 Textboxes which shall be filled with True or False if its reachable or not.

```
namespace Test_WebsiteChecker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void checkLinks_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            getTextBox0 = WebSiteIsAvailable("some website").ToString();
            getTextBox1 = WebSiteIsAvailable("some website").ToString();
            getTextBox2 = WebSiteIsAvailable("some website").ToString();
            getTextBox3 = WebSiteIsAvailable("some website").ToString();

        }

        public string getTextBox0
        {
            get { return LinkToCheck.Text; }
            set => LinkToCheck.Text = value;
        }

        public string getTextBox1
        {
            get { return linkToCheck1.Text; }
            set => linkToCheck1.Text = value;
        }

        public string getTextBox2
        {
            get { return linkToCheck2.Text; }
            set => linkToCheck2.Text = value;
        }

        public string getTextBox3
        {
            get { return linkToCheck3.Text; }
            set => linkToCheck3.Text = value;
        }

        public bool WebSiteIsAvailable(string Url)
        {
            string Message = string.Empty;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);

            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.Method = "GET";

            try
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {

                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                //TODO message für fehler?
                Message += ((Message.Length > 0) ? "\n" : "") + ex.Message;
            }

            return false;
        }


    }
}
```

I previously tried instead of the getTextBox0 the attempt to use inside the button function

```
linkToCheck.Text = WebSiteIsAvailable("site").ToString();
```

But this got me the error, that linkToCheck is not defined. Can anybody explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are the names of your textboxes? `LinkToCheck` does not equal `linkToCheck` C# is case sensitive.

Comment: variable names are case sensitive. You dont have ```linkToCheck``` variable, you have ```LinkToCheck``` instead

Comment: At one place you're using `LinkToCheck` and at the other `linkToCheck` , one has to be wrong. And try posting only the code you need help with, not all of it.

Comment: @Lithium oh my god... I knew my question was dumb, but I didn't think it would be that dumb. Thanks to everyone!